# Why am I seeing Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints when using self sizing UITableView cells in iOS 8?

Tags: uitableview, ios8, autolayout, interface-builder

I've used self-sizing cells quite frequently since iOS 8 was released, but recently I've been getting errors like this:

```
2015-07-31 08:25:10.610 Evensity[78297:3090623] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbae3485d50 V:[UITextField:0x7fbae3486ab0(55)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbae3424790 V:|-(2)-[UITextField:0x7fbae3486ab0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fbae3486990 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbae3487480 V:[UITextField:0x7fbae3486ab0]-(2)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fbae3486990 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbae0c525a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fbae3486990(59)]>"
)
```

This is for a very simple cell that contains a UITextField and nothing else.

[image]

It's hard to see from the picture, but the text field has a height constraint of 55, and vertical spacing constraints (top and bottom) of 2 each. Due to self sizing, iOS adds the UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height vertical size constraint of 59 (55 + 2 + 2). This doesn't seem like a conflict to me, but I still see this warning in the logs.

Also FYI, the broken constraint message appears immediately upon entering the screen; it's not dependent on scrolling to cause cell reuse.

What am I missing here that would explain this, and how would I correct this? From the user's point of view, everything seems to be working as expected. But, I'm a big believer that if auto layout is writing warnings to the console, I should be correcting them as they're bound to be a problem someday.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe each instructs the Auto Layout runtime to do something that contradicts the other.

Maybe try :

```
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Comment: There aren't any autoresizing mask constraints involved here; my question lists the four constraints involved. Three of them are constraints in the xib, and the fourth is the encapsulated layout height constraint. The three from the xib seem to add up to the same value as the encapsulated layout height, which makes sense because I'm using autoresizing cells, which are sized based on my autolayout constraints.